# How to add scrollable JTextArea to jDesktopPane

Tags: java, swing, scroll, jdesktoppane

I was try several opinion but neither of them it seams to work.

This method returns JTextArea

```
    private static JTextArea getJArea() {
    if (jArea == null) {
        jArea = new JTextArea();
        jArea.setBounds(new Rectangle(16, 153, 468, 139));
        jArea.setVisible(true);
        jArea.setLineWrap(true);
        jArea.setWrapStyleWord(true);
        jArea.setEditable(false);
        jsp.getViewport().add(jArea);

    }
    return jArea;
}
```

and i JDesktopPane i add this area with this code snippet

```
jDesktopPane.add(getJArea(), null);
```

And this not work, I was try to create a JScrollPane and assign JTextArea to him and add that to the JDesktopPane, but that also doesn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use [`JInternalFrame`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/JInternalFrame.html) too. `JDesktopPane` is supposed to be parent container for  `JInternalFrame` objects.

```
JInternalFrame iframe = new JInternalFrame("Title", true, true, true, true);
iframe.setSize(180, 150);
iframe.setVisible(true);
iframe.getContentPane().add(new JScrollPane(new JTextArea("TestText",20,20)));
JDesktopPane desktop = new JDesktopPane();
desktop.add(iframe);
```

Then add the `JDesktopPane` to e.g. `JFrame` and you are done.

Comment: Yes, basically that's it. Thank you.

Comment: Just have to add    ((javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicInternalFrameUI)        iframe.getUI()).setNorthPane(null);

to remove the nort title bar, and thats it.